# Best desktop platform for CRUD on an online Rails web app?

Tags: cross-platform

There are so many choices, i need a win/mac application capable of sending info to a rails app, i already have the rails app working on a server, so i just need basic crud activity via xml.

So what should you work this with , Realbasic, Java, Flex?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel like staying in Ruby then you could check out [Monkeybars](http://monkeybars.rubyforge.org/). I haven't done anything serious in it myself but it [seems nice](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-monkeybars/index.html), except that the lack of new [information](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/01/monkeybars-gui-mvc) on their site is a little discouraging.